# Transferring data between DOORS modules using links

Tags: hyperlink, ibm-doors

How do I use links in DOORS to transfer attribute data from one module to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's usually no point in *transfer*ring attribute data. The usual way is to *show* data in another module, so that the data you see in the "other" module is always up to date.

That being said, if you really have to do it, first create a column which shows the data you need using the Analysis Wizard.
Then use DXL to transfer the data to an attribute.

Example: Module "System Requirements" has outgoing Links to Module "Customer Requirements". Module "Customer Requirements" has an Object attribute "Priority". In Module "System Requirements" you want an attribute "Customer Priority".

Open "System Requirements", Open the Standard view. Use the Analysis Wizard to show "Priority" of the outgoing links (do not show attribute names, do not use recursive analysis). You should now have a new column "Out-links (...)" showing the customer prio, it should be the 3rd column in your view (usually, you should now use "Tools -> Support Tools -> convert Layout DXL to Attribute DXL" so that you have up-to-date data all the time. But if you want the data to be fixed): In "System Requirements" create an attribute "Customer Priority". Run the following command:

```
Object o
Column c = column 2 // 3rd column in the current view (starting from 0)
for o in current Module do {
    string prio = text (c, o)
    o."Customer Priority" = prio
}
```

Check the result and save the module.

Comment: Then the analysis wizard should be your friend :) Do you have all the information you need?

Comment: good. It would be great if you marked the question as answered (accept answer) so that other users find the information as well